# Tensorflow identifying GPUs, but not recognizing them under the list of devices

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, python-3.7

I have installed tensorflow-gpu version 1.15 on my profile on a cluster, which has access to 2 GPUs. I was able to verify this by running

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

The above statements yield the list of local devices as:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 17161457237421390575,
 name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 2136131381156225295
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device",
 name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 5626920946153973344
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device",
 name: "/device:XLA_GPU:1"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 1069390960246559975
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"]
```

which clearly shows the GPU devices listed. On further search, I learned that XLA_GPU correlates to a GPU capable of supporting tensorflow linear algebra routines. However, when I run the GPU test function

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

the output is False. I'm confused as to whether the GPU is not being detected here, or there is an issue with the tensorflow-gpu installation (which was through pip). 
Any inputs on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you the only person using these GPU? Do you have the log from the installation? If not, can you repeat the process in a virtual env? What OS and CUDA? Can you use conda?

Comment: I am the only person using these GPUs. Unfortunately, I don't have the installation log file, and also don't have administrator privileges. The OS is RedHat Linux 7. I did use a conda virtual environment (corresponding to Python 3.7) and CUDA 10.0.

Comment: So why did you install it with pip? Create a new conda env and use conda for installation.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is just a bug in the tf.test.is_gpu_available() function, as it checks for device_type "GPU, not "XLA_GPU". I think your GPU works fine, it is just that the function is misleading (it has been deprecated anyway). The best test is to run code and check that the GPU is being used with nvidia-smi

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I actually attempted to install tf-gpu with conda as well, but this was problematic. The GPU was not being recognized at all in this case, just the CPU was showing up in the list of available devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is to check if TensorFlow is using GPU is the following:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

The following will also return the name of your GPU devices.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

If a `non-GPU` version of the package is installed, the function would also return `False`. Use `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda` to validate if TensorFlow was build with CUDA support.

***Note***: `tf.test.is_gpu_available` is deprecated. Please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available)

*Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') instead.*

Best way to test is to run code and check that GPU is using with `nvidia-smi` as mentioned by Matias Valdenegro or run simple code as below

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

Output:

```
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]]
```